/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is full
I'm new to Ubuntu so I apologize in advance. I got my server up and running this week and set up jellyfin, which has been working fine up until now. I dont know if this is the cause but my boot drive appears to be full and I have no idea why. How can I access /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv so I can see what is taking up all of the space? Here is the output of df:
Filesystem                         1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                1622844      1960    1620884   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  119332656 113962688          0 100% /
tmpfs                                8114220         0    8114220   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                       1992552    133064    1738248   8% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                       1098632     27968    1070664   3% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1                         1921724676        28 1824032588   1% /media/library
tmpfs                                1622844         4    1622840   1% /run/user/1000

Any help would be appreciated.

try: cd / then df -hs * | sort -h work your way though the directory tree until you can work out where all the space is being used up

@moo
this is what I get when I try running those commands. am I doing it wrong?
root@sunny:~# df -hs * | sort -h
df: invalid option -- 's'

Probably the command should be du -hs not df -hs - see also No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?

Sorry, my mistake, Should be du -hs * | sort -h

@moo thank you that worked. just for clarification, this will only show directories in my boot drive right? i also have a 2tb drive for media. if thats the case I guess I improperly mounted that media drive and everything has been downloading to the 128gb boot drive.

traverse into directories that are very large with cd then repeat
